# vue 3 call child method in router-view

Tags: vuejs3, quasar-framework, quasar

I'm using quasar 2/vue 3, and I try to call child method from parent layout, how do I achieve this?

app.vue

```
<template>
  <router-view />
</template>

<script>
import { defineComponent } from "vue";

export default defineComponent({
  name: "App",
});
</script>
```

routes.js

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: "/Quiz",
    component: () => import("layouts/QuizLayout.vue"),
    children: [{ path: "", component: () => import("src/pages/Quiz.vue") }],
    meta: { requireAuth: false },
  },
]
```

QuizLayout.vue

```
<template>
      <q-page-container>
      <router-view ref="view" />
    </q-page-container>
</template>
<script setup>
import { ref, onMounted, toRefs, refs } from "vue";
const klik = () => {
  this.$refs.view.debugg();
};
</script>
```

Quiz.vue

```
<template>
  ...
</template>
<script setup>
const debugg = () => {
  console.log("function called");
};
</script>
```

I try to call debugg() from QuizLayout, I try this.$refs.view.debugg(); but its give error $refs is not defined, how can I achieve this?

Comment: You should wait until the child is mounted - and then use the `$refs`. Also, make sure that the current route is actually the route that renders `Quiz.vue` - VueRouter does not automatically navigate to a child route.

Answer (score 5):

You could try:

`<router-view v-slot="{ Component }"> <component ref="view" :is="Component" />                                      </router-view>`

If you use `<script setup>`, at Child Component, remember to expose the used method, according to https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html#ref-on-component